# In c,I developed game using graphics.h but in game blinking of colour is there

Tags: c, game-engine, bgi

In c I made game and in this game the c program execution speed is slow thatwise the function cleardevice() use to flicker(blinking) the screen. And I am using turbo c.so how to avoid flickering (blinking in the screen.and also tell me suggestions about writing the code because I am beginner coder.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define l getmaxx()
#define b getmaxy()
int go=1,x=0,y=0,e,w=0,s,scr=0,d=10,sp=2;
char sc[9],c;
void scorce()
{
 sprintf(sc,"%d",scr);
outtextxy(l-130,30,"score:");
  outtextxy(l-60,30,sc);
}
void randcar()
{
 int c;
 if(e!=3)
 {
  c=rand()%10;
  s=(rand()%(l-200-200+1-50))+(200);
  }
 if(c==3 ||e==3)
 {
   e=3;
   rectangle(s,10+w,s+50,110+w);
   if((scr==100 ||scr==200||scr==300||scr==400||scr==500||scr==50)&&10+w>450)
   d=d+1;
   w=w+d;

 }
 if(10+w>b)
 {
 scr=scr+10;
 e=0;
 w=0;
 }
}
void input()
{
   if(kbhit())
   {
    c=getch();
    }
    if(c!='a' &&c!='d' &&
    c!='p'&& c!='w')
    {
    c='d';
    }
    switch(c)
    {
      case 'a':
      x=x+sp;
      break;
      case 'd':
      y=y+sp;
      break;
      case 'p':
      exit(0);
      break;
      case 'w':
      break;
    }
     if((scr==100 ||scr==200||scr==300||scr==400||scr==500||scr==50)&&10+w>450)
      sp=sp+2;
}
void car()
{
  rectangle(l/2-75-x+y,b-100,l/2-25-x+y,b-10);
  setfillstyle(1,4);
  floodfill(l/2-70-x+y,b-90,WHITE);
  if(l/2-75-x+y<200)
  go=0;
  if(l/2-25-x+y>l-200)
  go=0;
  if((l/2-25-x+y>s &&l/2-25-x+y<s+50)&&b-100<w+110)
  go=0;
    if((l/2-75-x+y<s+50 &&l/2-75-x+y>s)&&b-100<w+110)
  go=0;

}
void strip(int c)
{
for(int i=0;i<200*b;i=i+130)
{
rectangle(l/2-5,i-c,l/2+5,90+i-c);
setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,WHITE);
floodfill(l/2,89+i-c,WHITE);
floodfill(l/2,1+i-c,WHITE);
}

}
void border()
{    rectangle(l,b,0,0);
 line(200,0,200,b);
 line(l-200,0,l-200,b);
 setfillstyle(1,9);// here is colour 
 floodfill(10,10,15);
 floodfill(l-10,b-10,15);

}

int main()
{ srand(time(0));
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
int c=0,x=10;
  clrscr();
   initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");

   while(go)
    {
       car();
      strip(c);

      input();
     scorce();
   border();
    randcar();
   c=c+x;
     if((scr==100 ||scr==200||scr==300||scr==400||scr==500||scr==50)&&10+w>450)
   x=x+10;
   if(c>13000)
   c=0;
 delay(50);
   cleardevice();
border();


   }
   cleardevice();
   int color=rand()%15;
   setbkcolor(color);
   settextstyle(7,0,6);
   outtextxy(170,200,"GAME OVER");
   settextstyle(3,0,3);
   outtextxy(300,300,sc);
    getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

In comment //here is colour,there is colour blinking.

Comment: There is no reason to make all of your variable names so ridiculously short. Programming isn't a competition of fewest characters, and variable names get optimized away by the compiler anyway - it only makes your code very hard to read both for us and for yourself in the future.

Comment: Use double buffering to prevent flicker (write to a framebuffer, then blit the whole thing at once).

Comment: OT: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) please use meaningful variable names.  Names like: l, d, c. gd. gx. etc are meaningless, even in the current context.  2) please consistently indent the code.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: Double buffering means repeat the step again after the cleardevice function

Comment: Don't clear the screen.  Just move the cursor back to the top left and draw the entire screen again.  The screen flickers because when you clear the device and then draw the screen is completely empty for a brief time.  If you don't clear the screen then the screen will never not have stuff on it and it won't flicker.